# sql how to make multiple copies of a row in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make multiple copies of the same row in a mysql database table.

The only column that changes is the "ID" which is auto incremented.

Is it possible to do this with an sql query?

Comment: show some records with your output please.

Comment: is the number of copies a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is possible.

say for example you have following database..

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id +++ Name +++ Dept ++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  +++ Albert  ++  IT ++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

So use this query..

```
insert into table1(Name, Dept) as select name, dept, from table1 where id =1;
```

Comment: And now you have Albert from IT appearing multiple times with different ID numbers. Normally, that's a bug.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity is there any way to make 100 duplicates without loops or reruns. I mean only using standard sql.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no problem.

Use the [Insert Select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) and select all columns except your ID.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id = 1;
```